# Ardour 6.5 to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 - libraries

Tags: 20.04, ppa, libraries

Instructions how to upgrade Ardour from original v. 5.1 to 6.5 in Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS can be found here: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/ardour-backports](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/ardour-backports)

After succeeding to get the required paths correct I ended up to a situation that Synaptic tells that it is not possible to install v. 6.5. And why ? Because there are several libraries (e.g. libc6) where the standard version in 20.04 LTS is too old for the installation. Any idea how to overcome this problem ?

As far as I know I have done all the required standard updates for the system.

Comment: We thing you certainly shouldn't do is to upgrade system libraries like libc. This may end back.
Why don't you upgrade your system to a newer Ubuntu like 22.04 LTS? Maybe this helps.

Comment: Standard normall upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 is not possible (see the notes for Ubuntu Studio). You need to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone makes the libraries available in a PPA, you cannot install Ardour 6.5 in Ubuntu 20.04.

You can install the latest Ardour 8.1.0 using Flatpak.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.ardour.Ardour
```

Comment: The given link in the question is for 20.04. What's the purpose of that (official?) link in that case if it is not possible ? Worth nothing ?

Comment: It is not an "official" link. PPA's are not official packages. You can contact the maintainers of the PPA if you want to, but there is nothing we (volunteers on this site) can do about it.